# Rails - When redirecting from one format to another the flash is not maintained

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, format

I have a Ruby on Rails 3.2 app with an action that redirects from a CSV request to an HTML request, but the `flash[:notice]` is not available after the redirect.

The first action looks like this:

```ruby
def first_action
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html do
      redirect_to other_action_controller_url, notice: "This message will be displayed."
    end 
    format.csv do
      redirect_to other_action_controller_url, notice: "The message will NOT be displayed."
    end
  end
end
```

So if you request `/controller/first_action.csv` it redirects to `/controller/other_action` but the `flash` messages do NOT appear. On the other hand, if you request `/controller/first_action` it redirects to `/controller/other_action` and the `flash` messages work.

So how can one redirect from one format to another and pass a message into the `flash` successfully?

Comment: Could you also include the `other_action` code?

Comment: I assume you have some code in the layout to display flash message? If so, try setting flash with: `flash[:notice] = 'Foo`.

Comment: Yes I have code to display the flash messages and I did try setting flash[:notice] explicitly first. If the same block was in the format.html section and you make a request without the .csv extension then the redirect passes the flash to the next extension. It seems the flash may be ignored or dropped on a CSV format request?

Answer (score 0):

Try appending the flash message as below:

```
def first_action
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html  
    format.csv do
      flash[:notice] = "The CSV is not available."
      redirect_to other_action_controller_url
    end
  end
end
```

Flash message will persist for one redirect action only. after that, it will go off.

Hope it helps :)